# How do I prepend text from one textbox to another?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Basically I'm making a simple program to help take notes at my job.  I have a one line `textbox1`, and a multiple line `textbox2`.

I want to be able to type whatever in `textbox1`, and then press "enter" and it show up in the first line in `textbox2`.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: using WinForm or WebForm?Have you try any luck?

Answer (score 5):

```
//in form constructor, or InitializeComponent method
textBox1.Validated += DoValidateTextBox;



//in another place of your class
private void DoValidateTextBox(object sender, EvenArgs e) {
  textBox2.Text =  ((TextBox)sender).Text + Environment.NewLine + textBox2.Text;
}
```

Comment: Here is my code:public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

Comment: I'm not sure where to add that code that you posted, and also not sure how to properly format.  Sorry

Comment: @Boneyards if you created the textbox1_TextChanged with the Visual interface, just go to TextBox1, choose the Validated event and add "DoValidatedTextBox" in the field. Remove the "textbox1_TextChanged" from the "TextChanged" field, paste the second part of code near the `private void textobx1_TextChanged` (which you can remove).

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) // Keydown event in Textbox1
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) // Add text to TextBox2 on press Enter
  {
    textBox2.Text += textBox1.Text;
    textBox2.Text+= "\r\n"; // Add newline
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty; // Empty Textbox1
    textBox1.Focus(); // Set focus on Textbox1
  }
}
```

If you want to add text at the firstline of your textbox, then replace in the code above:

```
textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text + "\r\n" + textBox2.Text;
```

Comment: this will add Text at last line, not first one.

Comment: Then replace with: textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text; or textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text + "\r\n" + textBox2.Text;

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want the final result to be.  If all you want is the first line of the second textbox to equal the first then:

```
void myEvent()
{
    textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text;
}
```

If however you want whatever is in textbox1 to be *appended* to textbox2 every time you press a button, then you are better off using a ListView:

```
void myEvent()
{
   myListView.Items.add(textbox1.Text);
}
```

If you specifically want a textbox though (with the data always appended to the first line):

```
void myEvent() 
{ 
   textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + textbox2.Text; 
}
```

Comment: I tried the last one but the Newline() was giving me errors.  I took out the () and when in typed in textbox1 it was showing the whole word on first line of textbox2, then whole word minus one letter on line 2, etc etc in real time.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code in a blank form and I'm not getting that problem.  Have you made sure that the 'Multiline' property on textBox2 is set to true?  Also it's "Environment.NewLine" without the brackets and with the capital 'L'.